# Is it correct to say "She rubbed her leg on something and had a thin bit of her skin almost falling off"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

My little daughter rubbed her leg on a surface and a bit of skin is about to fall off (see the picture).

Is it correct to say "**She rubbed her leg on something and had a thin bit of her skin almost falling off**"?

Comment: It's a much more complicated explanation than most people would feel the need for! You could say she grazed her leg (perhaps adding _slightly_, because a graze can draw blood). In British English we sometimes talk about _barking_ your shins - accidentally scraping some skin off, like peeling bark from a tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a US English speaker, I would say she [**scraped**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrape) her leg on something and got **a scrape**.

*scrape*: to damage or injure the surface of by contact with a rough surface 
*a scrape*: a mark or injury caused by scraping : ABRASION

*Rub* sounds much more gentle and does not imply any injury.